# Issue with a Spring integration test involving an entity with lazy collections

Tags: spring-test, spring-mvc-test, spring-security-test

I am experimenting with the new Spring Security Test framework. I have a test that involves returning a JPA entity with lazy collections.

The following test ends up in error because one of the lazy collections.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles({ Profiles.TEST })
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { FullSecurityTestConfiguration.class, FullIntegrationTestConfiguration.class, BaseTestConfiguration.class, WebMvcConfiguration.class,
        EnableHelperComponents.class })
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = { ServletTestExecutionListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, WithSecurityContextTestExcecutionListener.class })
public class CurriculumPermissionEvaluatorAuthorizationTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }

    @After
    public void clean() {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    }
    @Test
    @WithUserDetails("balteo@yahoo.fr")
    public void shouldAllowCurriculumRetrieval() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/curriculum/findCurriculumById").param("id", "1")//
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)//
                .header("X-Ajax", "true"))//
                .andDo(print())//
                .andExpect(status().isOk());//
    }
```

Here is the error message:

```
21:40:52.731 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
21:40:52.732 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@4a17c31]
21:40:52.733 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@4a17c31] after transaction
21:40:52.733 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
21:40:52.795 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ResponseBodyAdviceChain - Invoking ResponseBodyAdvice chain for body=Curriculum [drivingLicense=true, smoker=false, maxNumberChildren=2, workExperienceInYears=11, dateOfBirth=1975-01-06 00:00:00.0, telephoneNumber=0142778899, firstName=Juliette, visible=true, validated=true]
21:40:52.796 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ResponseBodyAdviceChain - After ResponseBodyAdvice chain body=Curriculum [drivingLicense=true, smoker=false, maxNumberChildren=2, workExperienceInYears=11, dateOfBirth=1975-01-06 00:00:00.0, telephoneNumber=0142778899, firstName=Juliette, visible=true, validated=true]
21:40:52.819 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum com.bignibou.controller.curriculum.CurriculumController.findCurriculumById(java.lang.Long)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum.workExperiences, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum["workExperiences"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum.workExperiences, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum["workExperiences"])
21:40:52.820 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum com.bignibou.controller.curriculum.CurriculumController.findCurriculumById(java.lang.Long)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum.workExperiences, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum["workExperiences"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum.workExperiences, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum["workExperiences"])
21:40:52.820 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum com.bignibou.controller.curriculum.CurriculumController.findCurriculumById(java.lang.Long)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum.workExperiences, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum["workExperiences"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum.workExperiences, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum["workExperiences"])
21:40:52.821 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name '': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
21:40:52.821 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

What I am getting wrong in my test setup? Why is the JPA entity manager being closed too early? How can I circumvent this issue?

**edit 1**:

Method from controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/findCurriculumById", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Curriculum findCurriculumById(@RequestParam Long id) {
        return curriculumService.findCurriculum(id);
    }
```

Method from service:

```
@Override
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() AND hasPermission(#curriculumId, 'curriculumByIdOwnerPermission')")
    @Cacheable(value = CacheConfiguration.DATABASE_CACHE_NAME, key = "'curriculum.Id:' + #curriculumId")
    public Curriculum findCurriculum(Long curriculumId) {
        return curriculumRepository.findOne(curriculumId);
    }
```

**edit 2**:

I realized that the test is actually in error even though I've annotated the test method with `@Transactional` as follows:

```
@Test
@WithUserDetails("balteo@yahoo.fr")
@Transactional
public void shouldAllowCurriculumRetrieval() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/curriculum/findCurriculumById").param("id", "1")//
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)//
            .header("X-Ajax", "true"))//
            .andDo(print())//
            .andExpect(status().isOk());//
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
16:54:31.747 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@ab4a4ae, returned: 1
16:54:31.747 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
16:54:31.747 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
16:54:31.752 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ResponseBodyAdviceChain - Invoking ResponseBodyAdvice chain for body=Curriculum [drivingLicense=true, smoker=false, maxNumberChildren=2, workExperienceInYears=11, dateOfBirth=1975-01-06 00:00:00.0, telephoneNumber=0142778899, firstName=Juliette, visible=true, validated=true]
16:54:31.752 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ResponseBodyAdviceChain - After ResponseBodyAdvice chain body=Curriculum [drivingLicense=true, smoker=false, maxNumberChildren=2, workExperienceInYears=11, dateOfBirth=1975-01-06 00:00:00.0, telephoneNumber=0142778899, firstName=Juliette, visible=true, validated=true]
16:54:31.767 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum com.bignibou.controller.curriculum.CurriculumController.findCurriculumById(java.lang.Long)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum.workExperiences, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum["workExperiences"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum.workExperiences, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum["workExperiences"])
16:54:31.768 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum com.bignibou.controller.curriculum.CurriculumController.findCurriculumById(java.lang.Long)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum.workExperiences, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum["workExperiences"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum.workExperiences, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum["workExperiences"])
16:54:31.768 [main] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum com.bignibou.controller.curriculum.CurriculumController.findCurriculumById(java.lang.Long)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum.workExperiences, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum["workExperiences"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum.workExperiences, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum["workExperiences"])
16:54:31.768 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name '': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
16:54:31.768 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request

MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = GET
         Request URI = /curriculum/findCurriculumById
          Parameters = {id=[1]}
             Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json], X-Ajax=[true]}

             Handler:
                Type = com.bignibou.controller.curriculum.CurriculumController
              Method = public com.bignibou.domain.Curriculum com.bignibou.controller.curriculum.CurriculumController.findCurriculumById(java.lang.Long)

               Async:
   Was async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException

        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null

            FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 500
       Error message = null
             Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json]}
        Content type = application/json
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
16:54:31.770 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
16:54:31.770 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@76d0bc1d]
16:54:31.771 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@76d0bc1d] after transaction
16:54:31.771 [main] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Closing JPA EntityManager
16:54:31.771 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Resuming suspended transaction after completion of inner transaction
16:54:31.771 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.bignibouX.tests.security.curriculum.CurriculumPermissionEvaluatorAuthorizationTest.clean]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
16:54:31.771 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@3972d402] for JPA transaction
16:54:31.771 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@21bcecc5]
16:54:31.771 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
16:54:31.772 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@3972d402]
16:54:31.772 [main] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@3972d402] after transaction
```

**edit 3**:

Here is the relevant part of Curriculum:

```
@Entity
public class Curriculum {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "curriculum")
    private Set<WorkExperience> workExperiences;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test method is **not** transactional.

You need to annotate either `CurriculumPermissionEvaluatorAuthorizationTest` or `shouldAllowCurriculumRetrieval()` with `@Transactional`.

Comment: Sam: I am so sorry: I've just realized that annotating the method with @Transactional actually did not solve the issue... My mistake for marking the answer as accepted in the first place...

Comment: What does the transaction configuration for `curriculumService.findCurriculum(id)` look like? Is the method, class, or interface annotated with `@Transactional`, and if so what is the `propagation` set to?

Comment: `findCurriculum` is `@Transactional` as per the following Roo ITD declaration: `declare @type: CurriculumServiceImpl: @Transactional;` The propagation must be the default one i.e. required.

Comment: As far as I can see, your test method will still need to be `@Transactional`; otherwise, your transaction (and therefore your session) ends when the call to `curriculumService.findCurriculum(id)` completes.

Comment: If you can't get it to work by ensuring that the test is _transactional_, it would be easier to assist you if you create a scaled-down [test project](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework-issues#readme) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you sure you annotated the test method with Spring's `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annotation?